# Plot PNG on Time Series Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

I'm trying to put an image on a time series graph using annotation_raster but because the y value is a date I keep getting the error"

"Error in UseMethod("rescale") :
no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of class "character"

Is there a way to do this using annotation_raster or is another method better?

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggpubr)
library(png)

###Set working directory
wd <- "E:/R/DataViz/Data" # top level working directory
setwd(wd)


###Make Data Frame
Dates <- seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), as.Date('2020-01-31'), by = 'days')
Number <- seq(1:31)
DF <- data.frame(Dates,Number)

###Import PNG 
mypngfile <- download.file('http://api.altmetric.com/donut/502878_64x64.png', destfile = 'mypng.png', mode = 'wb')
PNG <- readPNG("mypng.png")


####Plot Data
ggplot(DF,aes(x = Dates, y = Number)) +
  geom_line() +
  annotation_raster(PNG, ymin = 20,ymax = 30,
                xmin =  
                  "2020-01-06",
                xmax =  
                  "2020-01-27")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `x` values are date values, you need to use Dates for your `xmin/xmin` in the call to `annotation_raster`. Use

```
ggplot(DF,aes(x = Dates, y = Number)) +
  geom_line() +
  annotation_raster(PNG, ymin = 20,ymax = 30,
                    xmin =  
                      as.Date("2020-01-06"),
                    xmax =  
                      as.Date("2020-01-27"))
```